# Hover for Container and change bgcolor of Nested Div?

Tags: html, css, hover

First of all thank you for your time reading my question!

I m trying to do a hover code to affect an element (nested div's background color) and I found some answers and tried them but couldn't get it to work. Is there a solution to get this to work without using JS/jQ? this is part of a wordpress loop, so using jquery to select elements may not be the best idea. Any thoughts? Thanks!

What I am trying to get is that when the user hovers over any part of div#press, only the div#text should change it's background color to #FFF (div#press remains the same)

```
<a href="press.php">
    <div id="press" class="middle_bar">
        <div id="text">
            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
            Published <?php the_time('j F Y') ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

Thanks so much!

EDIT: It seems like setting a preset background color at #text breaks the code? Any reason why this happens? have attached the new code with inline styles

```
<a href="press.php">
<div id="press" class="middle_bar" style="padding: 200px">
    <div id="text" style="float:left; width: 380px; margin-left: -25px; padding: 20px; background:#999999;">
        <h2>1251515151</h2>
        Published 11111
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried the > and ~ selectors but they just don't work I can't figure out why

Comment: `div#press:hover > #text {background-color:#fff;}` is this what you did?

Comment: #press:hover > #text {background-color:#fff;} was what i did

Comment: so it should work, **unless** the background is overridden by some more specific rule somewhere else. In such a case try adding more selectors to your rule as many as possible, such as like this `:root body div#press.middle_bar > div#text {...}` and the last solution (when we can't make it specific enough) is using `!important` flag.

Comment: #press defaults with a background-image('bg.jpg'); would that actually affect the code?

Comment: My guess is that there is no other content inside #press except #text...so the whole thing turns white. Put some padding on #press to test. - http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/4ZH7c/4/

Comment: `background-image` won't affect `background-color`, **but** if the image is solid (does not have any background transparent), then you won't be able to see the background-color, of course.

Comment: seems like a problem with default bgcolor on the div#text, without it the code works for me, but not anymore once this is added how should I work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#press{
 background:red;
 height:50;
 text-align:center;
}
#text{
 height:50px;
 width:50px;
 background:dodgerblue;
}
#press:hover > #text{
 background:#fff;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/AQ2cQ/)

*If this isn't working for you, probably somewhere else you've a css selector having more specificity than the hover selector, may be inline styles... (injected by some script..?) )also watch out for `!important`*

Comment: Thanks for the tip, there were some inline styles indeed and I moved them into the global css and got this fixed!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the `:hover` pseudo class on the `<div id="press"></div>`. In addition, you'll need to use the `>` descendant selector to target the `<div id="text"></div>` child.

You should be able to do something like the following:

```
#press:hover > #text {
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

**Demo:** [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/warlock5658/4ZH7c/)